# How can I place a one-column-abstract in a two-column document?

Tags: two-column, abstract

How can I place a one-column-abstract and after that two-column-section in a LaTeX template?

Comment: This was (long long time ago) the first question who made me visit [UK-TeX FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?introduction=yes). And I found the [answer](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=onecolabs) there.

Comment: @Ignasi excellent reference! The link is now broken, the right ones are [UK-TeX FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/faq/) and [1-column abstract in 2-column document](http://www.tex.ac.uk/faq/FAQ-onecolabs.html).

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This should make the trick.
Important Note: This is a copy-paste from:
[I've just tested it](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-onecolabs)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
...
\begin{document}
... % \author, etc
\twocolumn[
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
      ...
    \end{abstract}
  \end{@twocolumnfalse}
]
```

Comment: Note that `\maketitle` must be included if you want to avoid a page break before the abstract environment.

Comment: Users are advised to see some of the other solutions at the linked page, which is an answer on the TeX FAQ. In particular, to get `\thanks` to work in the author list (instead of just gobbling the footnotes), use of the `abstract` package (and the `\saythanks` command it provides) is advisable. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80210/17427

Comment: Well this technically works, but it removes all space after the abstract. So some commands to put a sensible amount of space back in are needed.

Comment: Used `@twocolumnfalse` as well as the linked `onecolabstract` (with package `\usepackage{abstract}`) in a `\documentclass{IEEEtran}` but neither worked.

Comment: ... found it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140579/ieee-tran-one-column-two-column-elements-in-the-same-page-possible).

Comment: The key is the optional parameter for \twocolumn.  

ie `\twocolumn[\section{This should be a single column heading}]`

Answer (score 24):

If you use the [`multicol` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) then you can easily mix different column format

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[2]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13):

The \twocolumn-command takes an optional argument, which will be printed in one-column-mode.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what the accepted answer by GuillemB is about, isn't it?

Comment: @lockstep: No, he added an environment (probably he forgot \makeatother) using `@twocolumnfalse`, but the simple optional argument does the trick.

Comment: I stand corrected -- +1.

Comment: His added environment seems to be necessary if you want both the title and the abstract in there.

Answer (score 5):

If you use the `titling` package, which I do anyway, you can use the final hook it provides for `\maketitle` to hold the abstract.

For example, the following code defines a new command, `\myabstract[]{}`. The optional argument can be used to specify a different proportion of the `\textwidth` be used for the abstract. The default is `width=.8`. To specify something else, just use `\myabstract[width=<value between 0 and 1>]{}`. The mandatory argument just holds the abstract content.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse,xcoffins,titling,kantlipsum}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\coffin_new:N \l_my_abstract_coffin
\dim_zero_new:N \l_my_width_dim
\keys_define:nn { my / abstract }
  {
    width .code:n = {
      \dim_set:Nn \l_my_width_dim {#1\textwidth}
    }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \myabstract { O {width=.8} m }{%
  \keys_set:nn { my / abstract } { #1 }
  \SetVerticalCoffin \l_my_abstract_coffin {\l_my_width_dim} {#2}
  \renewcommand\maketitlehookd{%
    \mbox{}\medskip\par
    \centering
    \TypesetCoffin \l_my_abstract_coffin
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\author{A. N. Author\thanks{To somebody.}}
\title{A Gripping Tale}
\myabstract{\kant[1]}
\maketitle
\kant[2-3]
\title{Another Gripping Yarn}
\author{A. Nother Author}
\myabstract[width=.7]{\kant[4]}
\maketitle
\kant[5]
\end{document}
```

[image: two abstracts for two tales]

Although I've used `xcoffins` and `expl3` stuff (which I'm not sure I should be mixing at all), you can do this without the alien syntax, still using `xcoffins`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xcoffins,titling,kantlipsum}
\NewCoffin \myabstractcoffin
\newcommand \myabstract[2][.8]{%
  \SetVerticalCoffin \myabstractcoffin {#1\textwidth} {#2}%
  \renewcommand\maketitlehookd{%
    \mbox{}\medskip\par
    \centering
    \TypesetCoffin \myabstractcoffin}}    
\begin{document}
\author{A. N. Author\thanks{To somebody.}}
\title{A Gripping Tale}
\myabstract{\kant[1]}
\maketitle
\kant[2-3]
\title{Another Gripping Yarn}
\author{A. Nother Author}
\myabstract[.7]{\kant[4]}
\maketitle
\kant[5]
\end{document}
```

Note that the optional argument now just takes the number e.g. `.7` rather than `width=.7`.

Or, most easily of all, just using a `minipage` environment:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{titling,kantlipsum}
\newcommand \myabstract[2][.8]{%
  \renewcommand\maketitlehookd{%
    \mbox{}\medskip\par
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{#1\textwidth}
      #2
    \end{minipage}}}  
\begin{document}
\author{A. N. Author\thanks{To somebody.}}
\title{A Gripping Tale}
\myabstract{\kant[1]}
\maketitle
\kant[2-3]
\title{Another Gripping Yarn}
\author{A. Nother Author}
\myabstract[.7]{\kant[4]}
\maketitle
\kant[5]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, using strip did the job.

```
\begin{strip}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
        \begin{abstract}
            \input{abstract.tex}
        \end{abstract}
        \hspace{2cm}
    \end{minipage}
\end{strip}
```

Where abstact.tex just includes the text.