# How can I change the distance between abstract and section 1?

Tags: spacing, two-column, abstract

My LaTeX format is as follows:

> Abstract: Abstract goes here.
>
> Section 1:

It should be noted that my abstract is one column and sections are two-column.
Abstract and Section 1 are very close together. I want some space between abstract and
Section 1. I tried `\hfill` but it only affects on one column but at the beginning of
the second column the Abstract and Section 1 are close together. How can I fix it?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\renewenvironment{abstract}{%
  \noindent\bfseries\abstractname:\normalfont}{}
\begin{document}
\title{
\textbf{Title}
}

\setlength{\columnsep}{0.8cm}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract is here 
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
\section{circuit}
Circuit is here
\subsection{Noise analysis}
Noise analysis is here
\section{Circuit Design}
Circuit Design is here
\section{Simulation Results}
Simulation Results is here
\section{Conclusion}
Conclusion is here.
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{}Friis, H. T.: 
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

This is my first experience with Latex and it's a real pain...

Comment: Hi Amir, Please make sure that both your accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.  Also, you can format code by selecting the code and clicking on the `{}` icon. (For inline code, you can use backticks `\``.)

Answer (score 8):

You could just insert a `\bigskip` between the abstract and your first section. If this is not enough, add some more `\bigskip`s. One `\bigskip` is "worth" `12pt` by default (plus/minus some stretch/shrink). If you want less space, issuing a `\medskip` is 1/2 a `\bigskip` at `6pt` by default (plus/minus some stretch/shrink). And then there's `\smallskip` which is 1/2 a `\medskip` at `3pt` by default (plus/minus some stretch/shrink).

Alternatively, issuing a `\vspace{<len>}` (with an optional `*`) should also do the trick, where `<len>` is some TeX length (like `1cm`, say). More information on the `\vspace` command is available on [TeXBlog](http://texblog.net/help/latex/ltx-347.html).

The above additions to your code is manual, and therefore viable as a one-time use. However, it is also possible to (say) patch the `abstract` environment to automatically append a larger skip once it's done.

---

**Edit**: I assume your `twocolumn` document configuration stems from: [How can I place a one-column-abstract in a two-column document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28109/5764) In this case the use of `\vspace` does not provide any effective solution (nor does `\...skip` which is defined in terms of `\vspace`). I would suggest using the `multicols` environment provided by the [`multicol` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol), and use in your document in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{multicol}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol
\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\vspace{2cm}% Additional space between abstract & rest of document

\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[2-4]
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[5-7]
\section{Last section}
\lipsum[8-10]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: Abstract in single column/rest of article in double column]

If you need more than two columns, modify the mandatory `{ }` argument of `\multicols`. In the above example, the [`geometry` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) provides a means to modify the page layout/dimensions (I set the text margins to be `2cm` from the page border using `margin=2cm`), while the [`lipsum` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provides dummy text.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using `multicol` as others have suggested, you can just use the [`abstract`](http://ctan.org/pkg/abstract) package to control the formatting of the abstract.  You can adjust the space between the abstract and the beginning of the text with a `\vspace{}` command.

If you want more control over the title elements, I recommend the [`titling`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titling) package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text (not needed for solution)
\usepackage[runin]{abstract}
\setlength{\abstitleskip}{-\parindent} % make abstract flushleft
\setlength{\absleftindent}{0pt} % make abstract non-indented
\setlength{\absrightindent}{0pt}
% adjust the next two commands to set the size/weight you need
\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries} 
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont} 
\abslabeldelim{:\quad} % add a colon to the abstract title
% uncomment this next line if you want more control
% over the titling elements (texdoc titling for the docs)
%\usepackage{titling} 
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\setlength{\columnsep}{0.8cm}
% now make the abstract span both columns
\twocolumn[
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
{\lipsum[1]\vspace{1in}} % adjust the vspace as needed
\end{abstract}
]

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: This is the simplest & best answer for me! Note the `abstract` package is not needed to apply the `\vspace{}` command though

Answer (score 0):

This is what Werner is suggesting and works fine for me with the [`multicol` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol). I assumed that you have a two column document since you have the `two-column` tag.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\bigskip
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[2]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```