# \thanks not creating footnote in twocolumn article

Tags: footnotes, titles, two-column

I am trying to use `\thanks` inside `\author` in a twocolumn article. The document shows an asterisk next to the author's name, but the footnote is not appearing at the bottom of the first page or anywhere else in the document.

The abstract is one column and `\thanks` works if the multicol package is used, however it would be easier if the article is simply twocolumn. Here is a working example.

```
\documentclass [11pt, twocolumn] {article}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{abstract}

\begin{document}
\title{Latin text\\ \textit{and}\\ It's in Latin}
\author{James Smith%
\thanks{The author would like to thank someone.}}
\affil{USA University}
\date{November 2012}
\twocolumn[
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
 \blindtext
\vspace{1cm}
\end{abstract}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
]
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext
\end {document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is discussed in the TeX FAQ at https://texfaq.org/FAQ-onecolabs

(Where did you get the idea for the `twocolumn` hack from in the first place?)

All you need to do is `\saythanks` after the `twocolumn` hack:

```
\documentclass [11pt, twocolumn] {article}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{abstract}

\begin{document}
\title{Latin text\\ \textit{and}\\ It's in Latin}
\author{James Smith%
\thanks{The author would like to thank someone.}}
\affil{USA University}
\date{November 2012}
\twocolumn[
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
 \blindtext
\vspace{1cm}
\end{abstract}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
]
\saythanks
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext
\end {document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this solution! I found the `\twocolumn` hack on this website when I was playing around with getting the abstract to be single column. I searched for a while trying to fix this issue with `\thanks` so I'm surprised I never came across `\saythanks`.

Comment: @Forrest. Glad to be of assistance. I too looked around this site, and the solutions to the obvious question [How can I place a one-column-abstract in a two-column document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28109/17427) omit mention of the `abstract` package, which I believe was created for just this situation. In case it's helpful, the package documentation has an example of use that mentions `\saythanks`.

Comment: @Forrest: I have now added a comment to the accepted answer in that question too, linking to here.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that `abstract` is better treated as part of `\maketitle`, just like AMS classes do, but this unfortunately isn't true.

You can however do so by yourself and this will avoid losing the `\thanks`:

```
\documentclass [11pt, twocolumn] {article}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\newbox\abstract@box
\renewenvironment{abstract}
  {\global\setbox\abstract@box=\vbox\bgroup
     \hsize=\textwidth\linewidth=\textwidth
    \small
    \begin{center}%
    {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
    \end{center}%
    \quotation}
  {\endquotation\egroup}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\@maketitle\expandafter{\@maketitle
  \ifvoid\abstract@box\else\unvbox\abstract@box\if@twocolumn\vskip1.5em\fi\fi}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\title{Latin text\\ \textit{and}\\ It's in Latin}
\author{James Smith%
\thanks{The author would like to thank someone.}}
\affil{USA University}
\date{November 2012}

\begin{abstract}
 \blindtext
\vspace{1cm}
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\blindtext
\end {document}
```

Note that you *must* type the `abstract` environment before `\maketitle`, which shouldn't be a big issue.

[image]

**Note** I've changed the original code to work correctly also in one column mode

Answer (score 1):

use it this way, if you want the abstract over both columns:

```
\documentclass [11pt,twocolumn] {article}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{abstract}

\begin{document}
\title{Latin text\\ \textit{and}\\ It's in Latin}
\author{James Smith%
\thanks{The author would like to thank someone.}}
\affil{USA University}
\date{November 2012\\[1cm]
\begin{abstract}
 \blindtext
\end{abstract}}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\blindtext
\end {document}
```

[image]