# Footnote not showing in article's maketitle when using twocolumn

Tags: footnotes, two-column, article

I want an article with two columns and a title section, but without a separate title page. I have achieved that, but the author's email address is not showing as a footnote (tried using `thanks` and `footnote`). Here is my example

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[dvipdfm]{hyperref}

% redefine astract
\renewenvironment{abstract}
    {\par\noindent\textbf{\abstractname}\ \ignorespaces \\}
    {\par\noindent\medskip}

% title, author, abstract
\title{\textbf{Some clear title}}
\author{Jane Doe\footnote{\href{mailto:jane.doe@bla.bla}{jane.doe@bla.bla}}}
%\author{Jane Doe\thanks{\href{mailto:jane.doe@bla.bla}{jane.doe@bla.bla}}}
\newcommand{\abstractText}{\noindent%
    \lipsum[1]
}

\begin{document}

% starting twocolumn environment, and defining a header text in the optional
% argument of \twocolumn, where the header text is written at top of the page
% in one column with the width of the whole page
\twocolumn[
    \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
        \maketitle
        {\color{gray}\hrule}
        \bigskip
        \begin{abstract}
            \abstractText
            \bigskip
            {\color{gray}\hrule}
            \bigskip
        \end{abstract}
    \end{@twocolumnfalse}
]

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2]

\section{Another section}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Any hints on how to get the email address into the footnote is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optional argument of `\twocolumn` is put into a box. So `\footnote` does not work. You can, e.g., use `\footnotetext` after the title:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% redefine astract
\renewenvironment{abstract}
    {\par\noindent\textbf{\abstractname}\ \ignorespaces \\}
    {\par\noindent\medskip}

% title, author, abstract
\title{\textbf{Some clear title}}
\author{Jane Doe\footnotemark}
%\author{Jane Doe\thanks{\href{mailto:jane.doe@bla.bla}{jane.doe@bla.bla}}}
\newcommand{\abstractText}{\noindent%
    \lipsum[1]
}

\begin{document}

% starting twocolumn environment, and defining a header text in the optional
% argument of \twocolumn, where the header text is written at top of the page
% in one column with the width of the whole page
\twocolumn[
    \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
        \maketitle
        {\color{gray}\hrule}
        \bigskip
        \begin{abstract}
            \abstractText
            \bigskip
            {\color{gray}\hrule}
            \bigskip
        \end{abstract}
    \end{@twocolumnfalse}
    ]
{\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}\stepcounter{footnote}%
  \footnotetext{\href{mailto:jane.doe@bla.bla}{jane.doe@bla.bla}}}
\setcounter{footnote}{0}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2]\footnote{a real footnote}

\section{Another section}
\lipsum[3]\footnote{another footnote}

\end{document}
```

This is indeed not really an automatic solution, but it works.

[image: using \footnotemark and \footnotetext together with real footnotes]

Another suggestion would be to use package `authblk` and then use `\saythanks`. See “[\thanks not creating footnote in twocolumn article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80210/thanks-not-creating-footnote-in-twocolumn-article)” for more information.

Comment: these are two solutions, thanks a lot!