# single column abstract in an article and delete date below title

Tags: lyx, two-column, abstract

I am using LyX to prepare my journal for publication using `article` style.

I use double column article. When I choose abstract from left panel, the abstract turns out to be in left-column in double column in pdf output.

I searched around in LyX, but I could not find any option for making the abstract to be in single column and following texts to be in double columns.

Further, I want the date below the title line to be removed in pdf output.

How can these be achieved?  I wish I can get some help and appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### One column abstract

The LaTeX equivalent of your question is [How can I place a one-column-abstract in a two-column document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28109/how-can-i-place-a-one-column-abstract-in-a-two-column-document), and this is also mentioned in the [FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-onecolabs).

To do this in LyX you'll need to use ERTs I think, which is inserted with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

1. At the very beginning of your document, before author, title, etc., add an ERT where you write

   ```
    \twocolumn[
      \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
   ```
2. Add author, title from the top-left drop down menu.
3. Add your abstract.
4. After the abstract, make sure you're outside the `abstract` environment, e.g. by selecting the *Standard*  style from the drop down menu. Then add an ERT with

   ```
    \end{@twocolumnfalse}
    ]
   ```

If you look in the source preview panel, you should see code similar to this:

```
\twocolumn[
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse} 


\author{Who}


\title{What?}


\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Stuff.
\end{abstract}
 \end{@twocolumnfalse}
]
```

### Remove date

Go to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX Preamble, add

```
\date{}
```

### Screenshot of LyX view and PDF

I used the `lipsum` package and its `\lipsum` command to create some dummy text for this screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Dear Torbjørn T, thanks so much for your help. Your answer is perfect. Further I would like to know how to increase the distance between last line in abstract and first line in INTRODUCTION? This will make the page more nice I guess.

Comment: @Vijay Try adding some vertical space after the second ERT. I don't have LyX here, but it is somewhere in the Insert menu, possibly under Formatting.