# Remove white space before abstract

Tags: achemso

I am using Lyx and I made the abstract span the two columns as described here.

[single column abstract in an article and delete date below title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119278/single-column-abstract-in-an-article-and-delete-date-below-title)

but then a lot of white space is generated between the abstract and author affiliation. The abstract starts from a new page which I do not want.

I tried negative vertical space, it didn't work. I am using achemso package for langmuir style article.

Comment: Are you going to submit this to a journal, or are you just using that class because you like the style? The reason I'm asking is that if you're submitting to a journal with their own template, there's no point in making adjustments like these, as the journal determines the layout of their publications, not you.

Comment: I am going to submit it to s journal. But i still want to get it in the best possible format.

Comment: Point is, you don't decide what the format is, so I'm fairly sure it's a pointless exercise.

Comment: (in other words: they prefer all papers look ugly *but the same*, than one paper (yours) nice and the other ugly).