# \thanks within @twocolumnfalse environment

Tags: two-column

Following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28110/27466) I added one column environment to my two columns article. Yet the `\thanks{}` footnote is not typeset by LaTeX.

Here the MWE

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Something}
\author{Name \thanks{affiliation}}
\date{\today}

\twocolumn[
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
      \lipsum
    \end{abstract}
  \end{@twocolumnfalse}
]

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method won't work for thanks. Follow [the method described here](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-onecolabs):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Something}
\author{Name\thanks{}}
\date{\today}

\twocolumn[
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
      {\lipsum[1]}
    \end{abstract}
  \end{@twocolumnfalse}
]
{
  \renewcommand{\thefootnote}%
    {\fnsymbol{footnote}}
  \footnotetext[1]{affiliation}
}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Or use `abstract` package and its `onecolabstract` environment and issue a `saythanks` afterwards.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Something}
\author{Name\thanks{affiliation}}
\date{\today}

\twocolumn[
    \maketitle
    \begin{onecolabstract}
      {\lipsum[1]}
    \end{onecolabstract}
]
\saythanks
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is the `\onecolumn` command, for content in just one column, as is requested here for the titlepage. Afterwards, just switch back to `\twocolumn` mode.

I believe, that `thanks` footnote is confused on which column a footnote should appear, even it is in a faked twocolumn mode.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Something}
\author{Name \thanks{affiliation}}
\date{\today}

\onecolumn
    \maketitle
    \begin{abstract}
      \lipsum
    \end{abstract}

\twocolumn
\lipsum



\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note** The `\lipsum` command provides too much text for the title page, so the one-column mode lasts to the 2nd page too, in the true production run, this is no issue of course.

Comment: `\twocolumn` will cause a page break

Comment: @egreg: `\twocolumn` or `\onecolumn`?

Comment: Both, actually.

Comment: @egreg: Well, as long as it is the titlepage/abstract, I don't mind about a pagebreak. I am not sure, if the OP really wants to have a one-column abstract with footnote. If that's not the case, Harish's solution is the better one, of course