# Why my figure is not appearing?

Tags: floats, multicol

Could someone please explain to me why the figure in my code is not appearing when I compile the code thanks.

MY CODE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,hyperref,multicol,lipsum,geometry,titlesec,fancyhdr,amsmath,MnSymbol,wasysym,fleqn}%
\fancyhf{}% Clear all headers/footers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% No footer rule
\fancyfoot[L]{*\href{myemail}{\emph{myemail}}}%

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\geometry{margin=1in}

\title{Title}
\author{\textbf{myname}*}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Abstract
\end{abstract}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\thispagestyle{fancy}%



\section{Introdution}



some writing


\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$\mu(x)$
    ]
    % invoke external gnuplot as
    % calculator:
    \addplot[smooth,samples=180,domain=0.0001:20] {1/(1+(1/x))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}



some writing 




\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your document produces the warning `Package multicol Warning: Floats and marginpars not allowed inside \`multicols' 
environment!.` and that's the answer, multicol doesn't support figure.

Comment: Is there a way to fix that. I just need to plot this function 1/(1+(1/x)) with a caption under it in two column paper. Also the figure does appear when I remove the figure tag and leave the tikzpicture tag.

Comment: remove figure and use `\captionof{figure}{zzzz}` (`capt-of` package) under the `tikzpicture`

Answer (score 0):

If you're not too picky about where the figure is placed, there's a much simpler solution with a regular `twocolumn` article and the `abstract` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,mwe,abstract}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn[ % http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28110
  \maketitle
  \begin{onecolabstract}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  \end{onecolabstract}
]
\saythanks

\section{One}
\lipsum[2-4]
\begin{figure*}[tbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```