# AASTEX: one-column abstract in two-columns article

Tags: two-column, abstract, aastex

I am using `aastex` class with `twocolumn` option for an article.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,linenumbers]{aastex61}
```

I want my first section to start right after the abstract which is in a single-column format. I tried the `multicol` option but it is not recognized. I have also tried [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28109/how-can-i-place-a-one-column-abstract-in-a-two-column-document), which gives me error in the `\twocolumn[` usage. How can I fix that?

Comment: `aastex` is meant for submissions to journals of the American Astronomical Society; *they* decide how a paper should be typeset. With `aastex62`, I get the expected output.

Comment: ...also, [V6.2](http://journals.aas.org/authors/aastex.html) is available.

Comment: as others have said, this page break was a "feature/bug" in 6.1; it is fixed in 6.2 (I'm one of the editorial staff for the AAS)

Comment: @Gus, I tried the 6.2 and it works. If you write an answer I will be happy to accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page break after the abstract was a feature/bug in v6.1 (see [closed issue #38](https://github.com/AASJournals/AASTeX60/issues/38) here). It has been fixed/reverted in [v6.2](https://github.com/AASJournals/AASTeX60/releases/tag/v6.2).

(I am one of the Data Editors/AASTeX managers for the AAS Journals)